# C Signal timer for task switching

Tags: c, multithreading, timer, signals

Im building a simple task switcher that runs two functions in a loop. The idea is that it runs a f1 for an amount of time and then gives control to f2 for the same amout, then f1, f2, in an endless loop.

The problem is that whenever i run the program, the first switch goes well but the following switches never happen. Getting stuck in f2.

Ive tried other implementations archieving 3 switches at most (with the program getting frozen after that).

This is my current implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int count = 0;
int flag  = 0;

void f1() {
    for (;;) printf("A");
}

void f2() {
    for (;;) printf("B");
}

void sched() {
    flag = !flag;
    if (flag)
        f1();
    else
        f2();
}

void sighandler(int signo)
{
 printf("signal %d occurred %d times\n",signo, ++count);
 sched();
}

int main(void)
{
 struct itimerval it;
 struct sigaction act, oact;
 act.sa_handler = sighandler;
 sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
 act.sa_flags = 0;

 sigaction(SIGPROF, &act, &oact); 

 it.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
 it.it_interval.tv_usec = 10000;
 it.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
 it.it_value.tv_usec = 10000;
 setitimer(ITIMER_PROF, &it, NULL);

 sched();
}
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are calling code from within the signal handler and dont ever return from the handler. And allow it to (**recursively**) be interupted again. Also you should not call printf() from within a signal handler.

Comment: You might be able to get this to work (briefly, and undefined behavior galore) by setting `SA_NODEFER` in `sigaction()`.

Comment: I would take another route to solve this: Your signal handler gets a third argument when using `SA_SIGINFO` providing a `ucontext_t` structure with the just interrupted context. You can make use `setcontext` to switch between the two (or more) saved contexts to get results even closer to real preemptive scheduling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your signal handler calls `sched()`, which never returns (but ends up in either of the `for (;;)` loops). So after the first switch, you are always inside the signal handler, and further signals are masked.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that you have already been answered with the good answer

> Your signal handler calls sched(), which never returns (but ends up in either of the for (;;)...

the problem with your multitask implementation is that for a task switcher to work you need to do a context switch.  A context switcher is a routine that doesn't return until it has done all context switches to other processes and the next task to be scheduled is the one to return.  It's some king of call to

```
yield();
```

but the actual context switch ocurrs *inside* of yield.  A context switch is something that cannot be implemented as a simple routine (some piece of code that you call and returns)  because it mus return **in another context**.  For this, you need to call `yield()` and the code of yield must change all the cpu registers to the values they had in the *other* context (including the stack pointer, so this makes the appointment that you'll need *two* stacks) and then continue executing that code (that will make the program to return *in the other context*)

So you need to have some place to store the contexts of all the tasks you are going to allow to run in parallel.  This includes the cpu state and the stack of the task.  Then you need a routine (this is what does the actual context switch) that stores the old context (the one the cpu is using) in the save storage and recalls (and installs) the contexts of the new task to be scheduled.  Something like:

```
void task_switch(struct context *old_ctx, struct context *new_ctx);
```

and this routine must be written in assembler.... as it must do a context switch which includes switching the stacks of each task.

How do you see it now?

Comment: Yeah, this was just a reduced example, i have the context switch module working (i've done an entire thread library running 4M threads without any issue). Now i want to make them preemtive so im studying signal implementations. Thats were my question came from. Anyway thank you for your answer Luis!!

Comment: Then the problem is that one thread consumes the whole thing... you never get back to the scheduler.... you cannot get the second process starting, as you have only one stack.

Comment: @LuisColorado Just allocate more stacks, then you have many stacks. Thats not an issue.

Comment: @Ctx, the problem here is that the signal handler calls the switcher, and the switcher selects one task, which never returns.  So the program sticks into the signal handler that never returns.  He has only one task, as he never allocated a second stack for the other task, and doesn't do a context exchange... On those premises, there are no two tasks anymore... only and endless loop inside a signal handler.